# Use self-signed imported certificate in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

AWS ELB supports to have multiple certificates and I can add multiple certificates (both Amazon Issued and some certificates signed by Private CA in AWS).

I have some self signed private certificates which I have successfully imported and would like to use them with my ELB but the certificate list does not show these imported certificates. I can see these certificates under ACM (Amazon Certificate Manager). The certificates are imported in same region I have my ELB.

I don't know why it does not appear for ELB list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the certificate you loaded into ACM does not meet the security requirements for the ELB it will not show up in the drop down to be applied.  Check the security settings on the certificate and the requirements of the ELB and adjust as needed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html

Note:  You can upload your certificate to IAM and use it from there but this is not recommended.

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name mycert --certificate-body file://public.pem --private-key file://private.pem
```